# Why does my regex not match on html tags spanning multiple lines even when RegexOptions.Multiline is used?

Tags: c#, regex

I am attempting to strip out the tags out of the following text:

```
<P style=""MARGIN: 0in 0in 0pt"" class=MsoNormal><SPAN 
style=""COLOR: #1f497d""><FONT size=3 face=Calibri> </FONT></SPAN></P>
```

Notice how it's on two lines.  So when I try to use:

```
Regex _html = new Regex("<.*?>", RegexOptions.Multiline);
tempHtml = _html.Replace(tempHtml, string.Empty);
```

It matches the `<p>`, `<font>`, `</font>`, `</span>` and `</p>` tags but does NOT seem to match the `<span>` tag.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You should use HtmlAgilityPack instead of Regex to do this parsing.  It's much more productive.

Comment: I probably should.  I inherited this code from a coworker, and he seemed pretty sure that he couldn't use existing html stripping code due to MS word and such not outputting real html.  I don't know how true it is though.

Comment: This regex would also work: <(.|\s)*?>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure how REGEX works with C#, but most of the time you have to escape the < and >. this pattern worked for me in php:

```
\<.*?\>
```

Answer (score 3):

`RegexOptions.Multiline` handles the meaning of `\Z` and `\A`. `RegexOptions.Singleline` alters if `.` means all character *including* linefeed (= true) or exclude linefeed (= false).

So use `RegexOptions.Singleline` if you want to include linefeed in your tags.

*But*, I agree to the comment of Bryan Crosby, who advised you to use the HtmlAgilityPack for parsing html instead of regex.

Answer (score 1):

I think what Fischermaen is trying to say is that you're using the wrong option, use single line mode:

```
Regex _html = new Regex("<.*?>", RegexOptions.Singleline);
tempHtml = _html.Replace(tempHtml, string.Empty);
```

Then go download [Expresso](http://www.ultrapico.com/Expresso.htm) and you can easily try this stuff out and test your expression.